# How to set sample rate for pigpio deamon?

Tags: raspbian, pigpio

I'm using Pigpio library to generate a pulse that its resolution is 1 microseconds. I used to  ' sudo pigpiod -s1 ' to set sample rate for Pigpio but It appears error as in the figure below. Please give me how to resolve. Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The higher the sample rate, the more memory pigpio needs to assign to DMA sampling.

The error indicates that pigpio can't assign the memory via the GPU.  Either assign more memory to the GPU (I think `gpumem` or similar in `/boot/config.txt`) or additionally try the `-a 1` option to allocate memory from the ARM.

See http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigpiod.html for the options.

By the way 1MHz DMA sampling is really pushing the limit on the Pi and I would only use it if absolutely necessary.

Comment: I'm using wavePWM.py library to generate many pulses. The pulse that I want to generate has cycle T =25us (F=40khz). but when using sample rate 1 us, 2 us, or 4 us using  " sudo pigpiod -s sample rate  -a1 " to set sample is that pulse received has cycle random for each output wave ( sometime 30us, 27us or 29 us). Can you talk me what problems occurred?

Comment: The sampling rate has no effect on the output wave which always has 1µs resolution.  Use the default (5µs) sampling rate.  If you are getting random timings it will be because of memory bus contention.  Is your system very busy?

Comment: Currently, I'm using a cluster raspberry pi 3 consisting of 3 raspberry to generate pulse 40khz for transducers. I using wavePWM.py library to generate many pulses with a different phase delay that I received from Laptop via UDP port. But pulses that I generate is that have no frequency accuracy as I desired.

Comment: Can you give me how to solve the problem " Memory bus contention" ? Current, I using all 24 GPIO pin of Raspberry on each one. Totally, my system will need 64 output pin of 3 Raspberry.I using putty via UDP to use Raspberry. I think that the wrong frequency due to use many output pin on Rasp, is it right?

Comment: Open a new question and post the code you are using.  I am not going to speculate.